# Why do removal companies ask whether my company or myself is paying for the move?

Tags: relocation

Why do removal companies ask whether my company or myself is paying for the move? Is the quoted price going to be different?

I am moving from the UK to another country within Europe.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say where you are, but it is quite possible that the rate they charge a VAT-registered company may not include the VAT - whereas a consumer would have to pay the VAT.

It is required in the UK (and I believe across the EU) to advertise prices for goods and services inclusive of all applicable taxes. This is not the case when giving quotations to business who do not have to pay the VAT, so you will see advertisements for trucks that are VAT free (as they are commercial vehicles), but regular cars are usually advertised inclusive of the VAT.